# Constantly getting "Webpack Empty Context Error" when trying to require() local files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a ReactJS app made using create-react-app. It is structured as follows:

```
app
 | - public
 | - src
      | - App.js
      | - Index.js
      | - componentA
      | - componentB
              | - CompB.js
      | - componentC
```

with another local folder of markdown files structured like

```
files
 | - A
     | - A.md
 | - B
     | - B.md
```

and from within `app/componentB/CompB.js` I need to load in a markdown file using the `require` module. Where should I put my `files` folder and what syntax/path should I use with `require`? Thank you,

SkippyElvis

Comment: Consider: https://www.prerender.cloud/blog/2016/10/20/create-react-app-blog